# jqgrid + bootstrap in RTL alignment gets all messed up, assistance required

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jqgrid

recently, I've decided to allow my users to edit multiple fields on this grid.

For this page on my website, I've choose to combine elements from jqgrid, jquery-ui, and twitter bootstrap css framework.

When viewing the grid in English, or any other ltr language, everything seems normal, but when switching to rtl view, everything get corrupted, the columns get dis-aligned, and the checkboxes if that are uses to select each row disappear from view.

screen shot:
[image]

code:

```
    $("#list2").jqGrid({
        url:'get_applicants.php',
        datatype: "json",
         width: 900,
         autowidth: false,
         shrinktofit: false,
         height: 300,
         scroll: false,
         direction: <?=$web_dir?>,
         multiselect: true,
         gridview: true,
         colNames:['id', '<?=$mylabel["last_updated"]?>', '<?=$mylabel["job_internal_id"]?>', '<?=$mylabel["job_title"]?>', '<?=$mylabel["applicant_name"]?>', '<?=$mylabel["filename"]?>', '<?=$mylabel["recommendation_count"]?>', '<?=$mylabel["referer_name"]?>',
         '<?=$mylabel["media_id"]?>', '<?=$mylabel["ref_type"]?>', '<?=$mylabel["location"]?>','<?=$mylabel["note"]?>', 'status_id', 'job_id', ''],
          colModel:[
          // {name: 'selector', width:10, hidden: false, align:'<?=$col_direction?>'},
          {name: 'id',index:'2', width:0, hidden: true, align:'<?=$col_direction?>'},
          {name:'last_updated', index:'1', width:25,  sortable:true, editable: false, align:'<?=$col_direction_other?>'},
          {name:'internal_id',index:'9', width:20, hidden: false, sortable:true, editable: false, align:'<?=$col_direction?>'}, 
          {name:'job_title',index:'8', width: 60, sortable:true, editable: false, align:'<?=$col_direction ?>'},
          {name:'uname', index:'3', sortable:true, width:40, editable: false, align:'<?=$col_direction?>'},
          {name:'filename',index:'11', width:30, sortable:true, editable: false, align:'center'}, 
          {name:'recommendation_count', index: '13', sortable:true, width: 45, align: 'center'},
          {name:'referer_name', index:'4', width:40, sortable:true, editable: false, align:'<?=$col_direction?>'},
          {name:'media_id',index:'5', width:20, sortable:true, editable: false, align:'<?=$col_direction?>'},    
          {name:'ref_type',index:'6', width:30, sortable:true, editable: false, align:'<?=$col_direction?>'}, 
          {name:'location', index:'14', width:30, sortable:true, align:'<?=$col_direction?>'}, 
          {name:'note',index:'10', width:0, hidden: true, editable: true, editrules: { edithidden: true }, hidedlg: true, align:'<?=$col_direction?>'},
          {name:'job_id',index:'7', hidden:true, width:0, editable: false, align:'<?=$col_direction?>'},
          {name:'status_id',index:'12', hidden:true, width:0, editable: false, align:'<?=$col_direction?>'},
          {name:'empty', width:10, sortable:false ,index:'15', hidden:false, editable: false, align:'center'}
        ],
        rowNum:20,
        rowList:[20,40,60],
        pager: '#pager2',
        sortname: '1',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "DESC",
        caption:"<?=get_phrase("Applicants")?>",
        loadonce:false,
        postData: { 
                    uid:  function(){return $("#uid").val();},
                    medias: function(){return $("#medias option:selected").val();},
                    types: function(){return $("#types option:selected").val();},
                    jobs: function(){return $("#jobs option:selected").val();},
                    applicant: function(){return $("#applicant").val();},
                    referrer: function(){return $("#referrer").val();},
                    internal_id: function(){return $("#internal_id").val();},
                    location_id: function(){return $("#locations option:selected").val();} 
                  },

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Go to the following page and create your own bootstrap custom package, eliminating any elements that might come in conflict with jquery-ui, or any other framework that you wish to combine with bootstrap.

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html